# Scala calling a Object from a variable name

Tags: scala

I have a few objects created with a function called .clean in each one:

```
HiveCleanerTbl
HiveCleanerDb
```

These Objects need to be called dynamically based on a record based on an API call being made that will let my Job know what object to call for instance I have it hard coded right now:

```
def matchSchema(schema:Int): Any = schema match {
          case 1 =>  HiveCleanerTbl.clean(rawRecord)
          case 32 => HiveCleanerDb.clean(rawRecord)
...
```

Earlier in the code instead of hardcoding the possible Objects is there a way to dynamically have the object populated like:

```
val systems = List[(String, String, Int)] = List((hiveTbl,HiveTblCleaner,6), (hiveDb,HiveDbCleaner,7))
```

And I have code that looks like this:

```
systems.foreach(x => if(x._1 == systemName) {
              cleanObject =  x._2
            })
```

How will I make the cleanObject defined as the object I want to use that can call its .clean function?

Comment: What if you made another object that had knowledge of all the other objects and contained the function that I think would take systemName and determine which cleaner to use? Without knowing more about your design I don't know if you could encapsulate all the other objects in one but that might be a possibility.  You could also perhaps get rid of the other objects and have this function that takes in the systemName return a function to 'clean'? Again , hard to say without more knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

```
val systems = List[(Cleanable, String, Int)] = List((hiveTbl,HiveTblCleaner,6), (hiveDb,HiveDbCleaner,7))
```

Lets say your `hiveTbl` and `hiveDb` are cleanable and lets say `clean` method is available on them to invoke.

```
systems.foreach { 
  case (db: Cleanable, "cleanSchemeName", _) => 
   db.clean 
  case _ => () //ignore
}
```

If `db` does not have `clean` method then check the type of db and try pattern matching to resolve the real type of the `db` object.

Here is a general example how you can achieve this.

`Cleanable` gives `clean` method to `A` and `B`. List contains all cleanables so I can go ahead calling clean on each object without type casting the object.

Based on certain condition you can ignore clean some objects.

```
trait Cleanable {
  def clean(): Unit
}

case class A(a: Int) extends Cleanable {
  override def clean(): Unit = println("cleaned A")
}

case class B(a: Int) extends Cleanable {
  override def clean(): Unit = println("cleaned B")
}

val cleanableStuff: List[(String, Cleanable)] = List(("clean", A(10)), ("donot_clean", B(10)))

def cleanAll(list: List[(String, Cleanable)]): Unit = {
  list.foreach {
    case ("donot_clean", v) => //Ignore 1st object
    case (_, v) => v.clean() //clean other objects 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All your objects seem to be "cleaners" - so create a trait called `CanClean` that defines the method `clean(rawRecord: SomeType)` and a property `val schema: Int`. The `schema` will be populated in each object with the appropriate value. Then put all these cleaners in a `Map[Int, CanClean]` with key: `schema` and value: object: CanClean. Then you can do `cleanerMap(schema).clean(rawRecord)`. If you do not want to populate the `cleanerMap` by hand, you can use reflection to make a list of "all objects that implement `CanClean`".